# How to rewrite a SQL query that contains repeated SubQuery?

Tags: sql, oracle

Could anyone help me to rewrite a SQL query as below in short ? There is a subquery to be repeated.

```
update policy 
set totalvehicles = (
  select count(*) from riskunit 
  where riskunit.policyId = policy.id
  and riskunit.subtype = 7) 
where policy.verified = '1' 
and policy.Totalvehicles <(
  select count(*) 
  from riskunit 
  where riskunit.policyId = policy.id 
  and riskunit.subtype = 7
);
```

Thanks !!

Comment: set a variable to the value of the subquery and then reference that instead of repeating the subquery

Comment: What type of sql server are you using? sql-server, mysql... ?

Comment: Does it need to be in 1 query ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

This should work (assuming MySQL, also working for Oracle):

```
update policy p
inner join (
  select policyId, count(*) as n from riskunit 
  where riskunit.subtype = 7
  group by policyId
) ru on ru.policyId = p.id
set p.totalvehicles = ru.n
where p.verified = '1' 
and p.Totalvehicles < ru.n;
```

Comment: @fancyPants: I checked your query on Oracle, but error systax at "update policy p inner join". thanks

Comment: @latala The error message says, that the actual error is to the left of `update policy p...`. Are you running this in a stored procedure by any chance? Provide complete error message and code, otherwise we can't help.

Comment: @fancyPants: Thanks for your comment. I used Oracle SQL Developer tool to test. The error is: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword at line 2.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this because it's easy to insert a select above the from and see what would be changed.

```
UPDATE p 
SET totalvehicles = cnt.[Count]
FROM policy p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        policyId,COUNT(*) [Count]
    FROM riskunit
    WHERE ru.subtype = 7
    GROUP BY policyId
) cnt on cnt.policyId=p.policyId
WHERE p.verified = '1'
AND p.Totalvehicles < cnt.[Count]
```

Comment: thanks, it worked on MySQL, but in Oracle syntax for Update is different :)